How to configure a grafana dashboard for multiple influxdb datasources
We have two influxdb database. already one database is configured as data source in grafana and also i want to monitor the other source also
I'm new to grafana, So I'm looking for some suggestions from the people who are familiar with that
Responses are greatly appreciated!!

To add a new InfluxDB connection to Grafana, just follow this path:
Home - Connections - Add new connection - InfluxDB
